# Django - "Include" a block in several templates? Template tag? Something else?

Tags: django, block, django-templates

I have a little statistics block that I want to be available in several places: the profile page of a user, and a search page with a list of users.

What would be the best way to proceed in repeating this block? 
I come from a PHP background, and in PHP it would be a simple include with passing some simple arguments. In django, I basically want to be able to call something like :

```
 {% stats_block user %}
```

Where user is the object containing all the user info. I was thinking about a simple template tag, but the block is pretty big and I don't want to put eveything in one line in the template tag.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you mean by "put everything in one line in the template tag"? If all the information can be read through the user object then that's all you technically need to send to the template, and your template tag will contain any code to put additional filtered values in the template's context

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### include template tag

You can [include templates with arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include):

```
{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}
```

### Template inheritance

But the best way to repeat a block in all templates, is to have a base template say base.html:

```
<html>
...
    <div id="user-block">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            hello {{ request.user }}
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url acct_signup %}">Sign up!</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
 ...
    <div id="body">
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
 ...
 </html>
```

For example, the contact template could be as simple as:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    Contact use: foo@example.com
{% endblock %}
```

Refer to [documentation on template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) for more.

### inclusion_tag

Finally, another great option is to make an [inclusion_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags), which allows to hook some python context processing before actual template inclusion.

Comment: That's pretty much perfect, thanks a lot ! Sorry I can't vote up because I don't have enough points on this account yet :(

Comment: Use your other account then ahhahaha. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom template tag, which can render a specific template.
Refer [Inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

From the link: *Another common type of template tag is the type that displays some data by rendering another template.*