# Trouble with "extends" can be only used once in Django template

Tags: python, django, extends

I originally thought I would use {% extends ["filename.html"] %} to take html I've written in a template and put it into my main file, but since you can only use "extends" once, how can I have it so that my `sidebar.html` and `slider.html` are like snippets that can be put into my main html file, which I've called `list.html`

Here's an image of what things look like now: http://imgur.com/K5XKAcQ
Here's an image of the error: http://imgur.com/Uqs3iQo

Comment: consider using include!

Comment: Could you give me an example of what that might look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "extends" like referencing a base class.  Multiple-inheritance isn't supported (directly).  To include snippets of code in your content, use "include":

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% include "sidebar.html" %}
{% include "slider.html" %}
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#include) in the main template

Rather than adding a tag in the `sidebar.html`, in `filename.html`, add:

```
{% include "sidebar.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include) statement. Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142891/django-include-a-block-in-several-templates-template-tag-something-else).