# Django templatetags rendered as None in the template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

Somebody can help me how to solve this problem, why my templatetags isn't rendered in the template? but, only rendered as `None` instead.

Previously I working with `Django==1.10.4`.

[image: demo]

**1.** `templatetags/total_tags.py`, I already created `__init__.py` inside this folder.

```
from django import template
from myapp.models import Category

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def total_categories():
    """
    {% load total_tags %}
    {% total_categories %}

    used in: `includes/menus_dashboard.html`
    """
    print(Category.objects.all())   # this worked well
    Category.objects.all().count()
```

**2.** `myapp/dashboard.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Dashboard" %} :: {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="ui two column stackable grid">
    <div class="four wide column dashboard-menu">
      {% include "includes/menus_dashboard.html" %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**3.** `includes/menus_dashboard.html`

> The templatetags of `{% total_topics %}` is similiar with `{% total_categories %}`

```
{% load total_tags %}

<div class="ui fluid large inverted vertical pointing menu">
  <a class="active item">
    Dashboard
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Categories <div class="ui small label">{% total_categories %}</div>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Topics <div class="ui small label">{% total_topics %}</div>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Moderators <div class="ui small label">2</div>
  </a>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="ui icon input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search threads...">
      <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Another idea, I tried like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12143011. and handle it with `@register.assignment_tag`, but still doesn't work well and only `None` instead.

Comment: You need a `return` statement in the tag function: `return Category.objects.all().count()`!